# Padding Left and Right Using Core Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set padding left and right using javascript using this code but its not working

```
document.getElementsByClassName('className').style.paddingLeft = paddingOfUl.toString()+"px" ;
```

Getting this error

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'paddingLeft' of undefined*

Please help suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a *list* of elements, not one element. You need to index into the list to modify an element in it.

Just the first one:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0].style.paddingLeft = paddingOfUl.toString()+"px" ;
// Change here -----------------------------^^^
```

All of them:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
var i;
var padding = paddingOfUl.toString()+"px";
for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    list[i].style.paddingLeft = padding;
}
```

Separately: There's no need to explicitly call `toString` on `paddingOfUl`, it'll get done automatically if you try to append a string to a number. So:

```
...paddingLeft = paddingOfUl + "px";
```

...is fine.

Comment: If they change all elements with the given class, it would be simpler to change the class itself.

Comment: @thg435: More direct, probably not simpler. It's a pain to work through the stylesheets and do that. And of course, they may have a reason for doing it directly on the `style` (precedence, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through the elements:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.paddingLeft = paddingOfUl.toString()+"px";
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for-in` to loop node entries. That's not what it's for.

Comment: Fixed. Although I didn't think that it would be a problem in this case. (Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#arrayNote)

Comment: Sure it would, if any plug-in or library has decided to enhance the node list prototype. This is just a corollary of the reason you don't misuse `for-in` on arrays.

Comment: Just FYI, the reason I added a sentence at the top was to work around a Stack Overflow bug where it locks in a downvote saying "you can't change it unless there's an edit" -- even though you **did** edit the post after the vote. Because it was within the five-minute period, the system fails. I wanted to remove the downvote, so I had to put in an edit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName('className')` will return an array of elements.  Since an array does not have a style property you receive the error.

The code should iterate over the elements returned by the array.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className');

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
   elements[i].style.paddingLeft = paddingOfUl.toString() + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
// the above returns an Array-Like structure with a length property.

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].style.paddingLeft = "10px";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change style of any element using javascript as follow:

```
document.getElementById("nameofelement").style.paddingLeft="10px";
```

instead of **paddingLeft** you can also use **background="color"** or **color="grren"** etc..